# Web font loader with fonts.useso.com mirror

Tags: google-font-api, webfont-loader

The great firewall in China stops me from using google fonts.  There is a service that clones google fonts inside China called fonts.useso.com

Is it possible to use web font loader with this mirror? If so, please tell me how.

Answer (score 0):

The mirror of Google Fonts by fonts.useso.com is no longer supported as of August 31, 2016. Google is now hosting their fonts through a server in China. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39752405/4084574) for more.